# How to measure transmission fluid levels?

Tags: transmission, audi, transmission-fluid, a3

I understand the newer Audi A3's with either type of transmission (auto or DSG) has a really weird way to check (to normal pull the dipstick type checking) the transmission fluid. Can someone please describe how this is done and what tools/things might be needed to do it correctly?

Comment: I hope it's easier than the method for measuring the transmission fluid level in the newer Toyotas. That requires $400 in tools, a lift, and a scanner to do it right. And it takes the better part of 30 to 45 minutes. Just to measure the transmission fluid level...

Comment: @cdunn  Most techs measuring what comes out and installing that exact amount instead of the official procedure on the Toyota.

Comment: I didn't realize you actually asked questions I thought you only answered them 

Comment: @RobertS.Barnes - [Answer this one for me.](http://mechanics.stackexchange.com/q/36291/4152)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did a little research today and it does appear to be a little odd.  Apparently, the motivation is that they'd like to have a maintenance free transmission (i.e., no holes for customers to insert too much fluid into).

The best summary I've been able to find is as follows:

1. The transmission fluid must start at lower than 35°C.
2. Raise the vehicle on the lift, put the transmission selector in Park and leave the engine idling.
3. Check the fluid level at the inspection hold at the bottom of the oil pan.  At the correct level, a small amount of fluid will come out of the inspection hole when the fluid temperature is between 35°C and 45°C.

All that said, I can appreciate why they'd like to keep the casual customer out of the transmission....

Answer (score 0):

Most of the cars, in order to check the transmission oil levels they have two bolts after the transmission bell. The top bolt is for checking and adding oil while the lower bolt is for flushing all the transmission oil and renew it.

In order to check the level of the oil, jack up your car on jack stands in a flat surface, and you unscrew the top bolt. If it spills out oil then the level is fine. If not, you need to add the proper grade of oil till it start spill out.

Tools you will need are, 
 - A jack and jack stands.
 - An oil suction gun.
 - A wrench with sockets from 10 and above.
 - Torque wrench (Optional) for tightening up the bolts with the proper torque

Extra tip: Sometimes it is good to change the washer of the drain and fill plugs.

Comment: While you are quite correct about regular manual trannies, the newer automatic Audis are VERY different.